# How to listen output logs in ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm developing an API server with ASP.NET Core 2.2 and my server machine is Ubuntu 18.04.

I have a log file for my APIs states but I feel lack about the ASP.NET(Kestrel) state informations such as routing result to my controllers.

The ASP.NET generate logs like below.

```
ServerApplication> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
ServerApplication>       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET  
                         http://localhost:57904/api  
ServerApplication> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
ServerApplication>       Request starting HTTP/1.1 DEBUG
                         http://localhost:57904/  0
ServerApplication> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
ServerApplication>       Request finished in 36.827ms 200 
ServerApplication> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
```

I want to listen or catch these logs to put to my log file.

I'd read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) but It seems not talking about listening the logs.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: You can try out Serilog , it provides you various options to enrich and log the events across different formats and destinations.

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee I have my own logging API and I don't feel it is bad. I just want to know about Kestrel's states. Not logging APIs.

Comment: so I see that  you wrote your own custom event sink.. good..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tuned `Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File`.

```
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Core;
using Serilog.Events;

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
                      IHostingEnvironment env,
                      ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddSerilog(
        new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Sink(new LogEventSink())
            .CreateLogger());
}

public class LogEventSink : ILogEventSink
{
    public void Emit(LogEvent logEvent)
    {
        string message = logEvent.RenderMessage();
        // Write to my log.
    }
}
```